# Finding the sequence with the smallest sum in array

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

> Given array $A$ of $n$ real numbers. find in $O(n)$ time the sequence with the smallest sum. in other words to find the indexes $1\leqslant i\leqslant j \leqslant n$ that gives the minimum sum of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{j}A[k]$.
>
> For example: for the array $[2,-3,0,1,-4,7,-5]$ the sequence $[-3,0,1,-4]$ with sum $-6$ is the optimal sequence.

*Attempt:*

Let $S(j)$ be the sum of the optimal sequence that ends in the $j$-th cell. in the example:
$$S(1)=2\\
S(2)=-3\\
S(3)=-3\\
S(4)=-2\\
S(5)=-6\\
S(6)=1\\
S(7)=-5$$

therefore:

$$S(j)=\begin{cases}0\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad,j=0\\
\min\{A[j]+S(j-1),A[j]\}\quad ,j>0\end{cases}$$

---

for finding $i$ :

Let $i(j)$ be the index that the optimal sequence starts. in the given example:

$$i(1)=1\\
i(2)=2\\
i(3)=2\\
i(4)=2\\
i(5)=2\\
i(6)=2\\
i(7)=7$$

> Need help on how to find $i$

Comment: Hint: consider the sequence of partial sums of the given array. What do you want to find in this sequence in order to solve the original problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as 
[wikipedia : Maximum subarray problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane.27s_algorithm)

You can apply the Kadane's algorithm to the array -A [ ] (thus will find the minimum).